# Reflow soldering, pin longer than pad?

Tags: footprint, reflow, ipc

I was designing the footprint for this FPC connector: [Datasheet](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/526101072_sd.pdf)

The recommended land pattern is shown here:

[image]

The issue I encountered is that the pins on one side protrude outside of the pad:

[image]

[image]

I triple checked the dimensions and the outer "toes" and the "heel" on one of the sides seem fine.

[image]

Would the absence of the "heel" fillet on one of the sides be an issue? It's not that I think that Molex has provided a bad footprint but more that I fear I might have misinterpreted something.

[image]

Source: IPC-A-610D

**Update**

These are the measurements on the land pattern depicted above:

[image]

I moved the pads to be 2.9mm center to center, and this is the result:

[image]

Which is weird, because the long pad is still on the short "pin". Flipping the part to match the long pin with the long pad, this is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Time to get out the digital calipers and see if both the part and the board match the documentation.  Anyone doing PCB design work *must* have a pair on their desk, and it's not like they are expensive anymore - you don't need toolroom machinist level accuracy or traceability.

Comment: DWG. says "MISALIGNMENT OF SOLDER TAILS FROM  F UPPER DIREVTION : 0.05 MAX.    LOWER DIRECTION :0.15 MAX"  How much is your result?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 - I think that refers to the coplanarity of the pins on the board, I am worried about the length of the pin vs the pad.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - yes I have some calipers as I also design mechanical parts but I don't always have samples of the parts I'm gonna use on hands. And even if they match the datasheet my question would still exist, so I thought I would post it anyway.

Comment: The stark contrast between the matchup shown in the drawing and that achieved on your board makes it very likely that a mistake was made somewhere - in the data sheet itself, in its interpretation, in the board design, even in its fabrication.  Using the calipers now can help you figure out what the mistake, if any, specifically was.  Distinct from if your current set of boards are a workable prototype, it would be better to improve the match next time around and make it more like the design depicted in the drawing.

Comment: What is the designed spacing of your pads?  The data sheet is confusing, because if read literally the 2.9 mm dimension is *not* the centerline spacing, but rather **somewhat absurdly the spacing from the _inside_ edge of one row to the center of the other**.

Comment: @ChrisStratton That was a nice catch :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Yes I used the 2.9mm distance from edge of one pad to (not even the center of the other, but) this super weird division of 0.9mm and 0.95mm (added a screenshot). (And I don't know what you mean by fabricated boards, I haven't made any yet, I'm just asking now to avoid issues during reflow - such as the connector floating and moving away).

Comment: That's what it *literally* says, but measure the part, maybe the dimension was misapplied to the drawing.  If you moved your pads so they were 2.9 mm center-to-center, would they better fit the part?  If you haven't ordered the boards yet, then by all means try to sort this out before you buy them!   Though if that is a 3d model of the part, I'd also want to cross check it for accuracy; once you have a discrepancy you should really be in "believe nothing not personally verified" mode.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - ah ok, now I got what you meant. So, I changed the pads to be 2.9mm center to center, and flipped the part so that the long pin matches the long pad. The pins now fit the pads but the toe dimensions now are assymetric. I think I will just get a sample part and update the question when I have some answers. There isn't much that can be done without speculating too much.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not a big deal, since that portion of the pin looks to actually be rounded and not square, which is hard to see in the picture below:

[image]
Source: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/fpc-connectors/7883521/

The dimensions in the datasheet don't show the rounded inside of the connectors which would make it easier to solder and align itself on the pads. I don't know that I'd even worry about if the quantities of the board were low (like 100 or less).

Answer (score 1):

Your part's data sheet rather dubiously shows 2.9 mm as the distance from the *inner edge* of one pad, to the *centerline* of the other.  This is highly unusual, and given the alignment mismatch you are seeing, has a strong possibility of being a drafting mistake.

It's not clear what all of the features in your renderings represent, but the first ("unflipped") achieved by assuming that the 2.9 mm is actually a center-to-center distance looks the best of the three (original, adjusted, and adjusted+flipped).  If it were me, I would go with that, or at least something based on it.

But more importantly, once a discrepancy is detected, I would "trust nothing" (neither data sheet nor 3d model) and instead personally verify *all* dimensions with calipers before ordering the boards.